# Automating login process using requests module python

Tags: google-chrome, python, automation, url

When I paste this URL (below) into my web browser... Chrome 
https://login.oracle.com/mysso/signon.jsp (Oracle login)
I get an error saying ...

```
Error! Do not use bookmarked URL.
Please type the URL you are trying to reach directly into your browser.
```

But when I put http://hudsonci.oraclecorp.com/jenkins/rgbu_jenkins/ I am redirected to Oracle Login  .

But when I am trying to do the same using **requests module in python** it gives following :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Single Sign-On</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/oam/pages/css/login_page.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/oam/pages/css/general.css" >

<!-- Start Disable frame hijacking Script-->

<style id="antiClickjack">body { display: none !important; }</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

if (self === top) {
   var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
   antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
} else {
    top.location = self.location;
}
</script>

<!-- End Disable frame hijacking Script--> 

<style>
body
{
    background:url('/oam/pages/images/loginpage_bg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#185E87;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div Style="position:absolute; visibility:show; left:0px; top:0px;z- index:1">
<img src="/oam/pages/images/login_logo.png" />
</div>
<div Style="position:relative; visibility:show; left:0px; top:0px;z-index:1">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="login-header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="login">
                <div id="title">Error</div>
                <div class="message-row">
                    <p class="loginFailed">System error. Please re-try your action. If you continue to get this error, please contact the Administrator.</p>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        
<div class="login-footer-version">
    <div class="info">

    <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 1996,2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.</p>
    <p id="trademark">Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.</p>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Following is my python code:

```
import sys
import requests

def mprint(x):
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    return

URL = 'https://hudsonci.oraclecorp.com/jenkins/rgbu_jenkins'


mprint('[-] Initialization...')
    s = requests.session()
    print 'done'

mprint('[-] Trying loginSuccess.jsp...')
r = requests.get(URL)
if r.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
    print 'error'
    exit(1)
print 'done'
```

I want to know why is this not happening with requests, and what are the other methods I can use.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think this off-topic here but should fit our sister site [SO] better.

Comment: Btw it's solved [Link to solution gist](https://gist.github.com/lordzuko/9f3df89ecc0200e66f1e28c1366192ac)

Comment: If you flag it for moderator review and explain it will get migrated.